# Как правильно добавить значения в QComboBox(PySide)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside

Сделал форму в QtDesigner.
Конвертировал в код с помощью pyside-uic.
Готовый py файл подключил к основной форме.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import InterfaceForm


class MainDialog(QDialog, InterfaceForm.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Каким образом теперь я могу добавлять значения в QComboBox из этого кода ?

Конвертированный

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(760, 248)
        self.allClass = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.allClass.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 761, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.allClass.setFont(font)
        self.allClass.setObjectName("allClass")
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(Dialog)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 761, 192))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим в документацию [QComboBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qCombobox.html) и в `MainDialog` в `__init__`:

```
self.allClass.addItem('a')
self.allClass.addItem('b')
self.allClass.addItem('c')

for i in range(10):
    self.allClass.addItem(str(i))
```

Если вне класса, тогда `self` заменяется на название переменной и: `form.allClass.addItem('a')`

---

Как-то заморачивался для [заполнения комбо-бокс](https://github.com/gil9red/client_readmanga.me/blob/cc8f899b249cfb324dd8ba3de7c8b3253613ce8b/main.py#L261) списком глав

Comment: Благодарю. Как всегда из за не внимательности пытался выполнить self.allClass.addItem('a') вне def __init__

Comment: @Stan, бывает :)